# If the Jacobian matrix is positive definite, does that imply that the optimization problem has a unique solution?

Tags: matrices, optimization

My PhD adviser told me that
if the Jacobian matrix of the optimality conditions is positive definite,
then it implies that the optimization problem has a unique solution.
I was wondering what is the basis for this statement,
in other words, what theorem or proposition gives this statement.

Here is a simple example which illustrates the statement.

Let $a, b > 0$ be positive constants.
Our goal is to compute the $(p, q)$ which maximizes the objective
$$
ap - bp^2 + bpq - bq^2.
$$
The first-order optimality conditions are:
$$
a - 2bp + bq = 0, \\
bp - 2bq = 0.
$$
If we take the Jacobian matrix of the vector-valued function
which is the optimality conditions,
it gives us the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2b & b \\
b & -2b
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

If I were to change the signs of the optimality conditions,
I could get the Jacobian to be the positive definite matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2b & -b \\
-b & 2b
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

What mathematical theorem or proposition tells us that
because the Jacobian matrix is positive definite,
therefore the optimization problem has a unique solution?

Comment: I think you are confusing the Jacobian with the Hessian matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positive definiteness of the Hessian is equivalent to *convexity* for twice differentiable functions, and convexity is what's really at work here. So, the theorem you want is

> **Theorem** Let $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ be strictly convex, where $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex. Then if $f$ has a local minimum in $U$, it has a global minimum.

You'll observe that looks weaker than your advisor's claim might have sounded: there are convex functions with no minimum, the simplest example being $e^x$.
But it's easy to find local minima of differentiable functions, certainly in your case when the first derivatives form a linear system, so then you can be sure of a global minimum.

Comment: Your theorem tells us that every local minimum is a global minimu. However, this does not necessarily imply that the solution is unique.

Comment: It's not necessarily unique even if it does exist-I should have said this, thanks for reminding. All one gets is that the set of minimizing points is convex.

Comment: I think it is possible to prove that the global solution is unique in the case of quadratic problems with positive definite Hessian under linear constraints (where the stated problem belongs to). Unfortunately, I can't find any reference.

Comment: Oh, no, I'm mixing up positive definite and semidefinite. For a positive definite hessian the derivative is a locally invertible map, so there can't be multiple solutions, quadratic or no.

Answer (score 0):

So, let me explain you. 
If a function is defined on a convex set and derivative(on its domain) and also its second derivation is positive, then this function is convex.

An extremely easy example is $f(x)=x^2, x \in \mathbb{R}$

So for multivariate functions this theorem results in the fact that Jacobian is positive definite.

Roughly speaking, positive definite in matrices (in $\mathbb{R}^m$) is equivalent to being positive in $\mathbb{R}$.

Convex optimization by Steve Boyd, [Click here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mYm0bLd3fcoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=convex%20optimization&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D8nbU6GnGunF7AbRxoCQAw&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=convex%20optimization&f=false) is the best reference for your question.