# Positive definite Jacobian matrix at any solution to system of equations sufficient for uniqueness?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-system

I have a system of non-linear equations, $F(x) = 0$, with smooth $F : U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $U$ is compact, where it's relatively easy to show that 1) a solution exists, and 2) at any solution, the Jacobian of $F$ is positive definite. [This thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823277/if-the-jacobian-matrix-is-positive-definite-does-that-imply-that-the-optimizati) seems to imply that if the Jacobian of $F$ is positive definite everywhere, then the set of solutions is convex (almost uniqueness). In my case, the Jacobian is not necessarily positive definite everywhere; despite this, are conditions (1) and (2) sufficient for the set of solutions to be convex? This seems true when $n = 1$, but I don't have a good intuition on this problem for $n > 1$.

Comment: It seems like an antiderivative of $F$ is quasiconcave. Thinking of solving $F(x)=0$ as finding the minimum of an antiderivative of $F$, I think the conditions are sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for this! This inspired some thought and I think we need slightly stronger conditions, that 1) a solution exists, 2) anywhere $F(x)' dx = 0$, for $dx \neq 0$ (and where $'$ denotes transpose), the Jacobian of $F$ is positive definite, and 3) $U$ is convex.